# How to generate ERD out of sql file using doxygen?

Tags: php, mysql, doxygen, graphviz, erd

I am trying to get familiar with doxygen and learnt just to comment php code and document them. I have read that doxygen could generate ERD like the mediwiki erd below and it is generated by doxygen.

[Screenshot http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/MediaWiki_database_schema_1-19_%28r102798%29.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/MediaWiki_database_schema_1-19_%28r102798%29.png)

I couldn't find any tutorials which could guide me to generate Mysql erd using doxygen. If its not possible or complicated, please suggest any other tool which could generate erd out of sql files better than doxygen. Its more preferable if i could get some tips on generating entity relationship diagram from doxygen itself as I have already documented the code using that. Thanks in advance

Update - I found that doxygen uses Grapviz library to generate ERD, how it can be done? I couldn't find any proper article or documentation either in graphviz website or doxygen website. If anyone could find it, please share with me.

Comment: The screenshot is missing. Can you add that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Schemaspy is a better alternative and this tool uses graphviz on the background to plot ER diagrams.